# Refactor Python Code

Tags: python

I was wondering if anyone could help me refactor the following Python code:

In this example, `endDate` is a string like such: `"2012-08-22"`

```
dateArray = [int(x) for x in endDate.split('-')]
event.add('dtend', datetime(dateArray[0], dateArray[1], dateArray[2]))
```

I appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better use `datetime.strptime`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> strs = "2012-08-22"
>>> datetime.strptime(strs,'%Y-%m-%d')
datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 22, 0, 0)
```

For your code:

```
event.add('dtend', datetime.strptime(endDate,'%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
from datetime import strptime
event.add('dtend', strptime(endDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
```